# Maven archetype from project with parameters

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I want to create archetype from project. But this archetype need to be parametrized. I added my custom parameter to archetype-metadata.xml but it is removed from generated archetype(/target/generated-sources/archetype/src/main/resources/META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml).

```
<requiredProperties>
    <requiredProperty key="custom_parameter"/>
    ...
```

What i'm doing wrong?

The second thing is that i need to edit some xml files. In archetype it should contain my paramter(${custom_parameter}). Can it be done by, for example, groovy during archetype generation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the `archetype:create-from-project` goal? Then you need to specify the parameter `propertyFile` (http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/create-from-project-mojo.html#propertyFile) to specify the replacements during the creation of your archetype.

I do not completely understand your second point, but as far as I know you cannot run code during the generation of a project from an archetype. You can specify custom properties, though (as above), but this is pure text replacement thing. Maybe you can achieve more elaborate things through the embedded Velocity engine.

Comment: Yes, you can do advanced processing with Velocity. [Here's an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23938386/944849)

Comment: Property file working well. Thanks. Now i need to put those values to project files. For example i gave projectAuthor property and need to put it value to <author></author> tag in xml file. How to do that?

Comment: When i add ${author} to the xml file after archetype generatrion i got ${symbol_dollar}{author}. There is no possibility to add properties to the project?

Comment: Ok. I find out that value from property is changed to property name during archetype generation. Thanks for help