# How to create multiple files using one template in Maven Custom Archetype (Apache Velocity)?

Tags: java, maven, velocity

What I want to achieve is use the code below from **archetype-metadata.xml** in order to create as many files as the items below, from **one template**.

```
<requiredProperty key="item_1">
    <defaultValue>item_1</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>
.
.
.
<requiredProperty key="item_n">
    <defaultValue>item_n</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quit using Custom Maven Archetypes because it can't create multiple files from one template. Instead, I used the Velocity Engine and I was able to do all what I want with complete freedom.

Answer (score 0):

The metadata file is part of the archetype, which you as the archetype developer provide, so your users won't be editing that file. If you need to modify file content, you can use Apache Velocity. Consider adding one property with comma-delimited values (or other appropriate char delimiter), where the default is a single value:

```
<requiredProperty key="itemList">
    <defaultValue>item_1</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>
```

Then, use Apache Velocity to loop through the provided values in itemList, adding the appropriate code blocks. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23938386/944849) for the idea.

I am not sure if it's possible to use this technique to create separate files, but it's where I'd start exploring.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have already used one single property with comma-delimited values, and I can extract them using Velocity, but what I need to do is create multiple files named with these values, using only one template like ____item____.java

Comment: I don't see anything in the archetype docs that allows you to do what you seek. You might get more clues from checking the source code for the plugin.

Comment: I did many research and I didn't find any answer, do you have an idea on how to create separate files using one template ?

Comment: I do not think this is possible, short of writing your own plugin.

Comment: Do you have anything that might be helpful for writing my own plugin ?

Comment: Sorry, no. I know how to use the existing archetype plugin. There are developer guides/blogs out on the web I believe.